# Question about Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Usually the stochastic integral is defined for processes indexed over $[0,\infty).$

I wonder about the standard way to define the integral for processes indexed over $[0,T].$ That is, for a continuous local martingale $M = (M_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ and a progressive process (sufficiently integrable) $H = (H_t)_{t \in [0,T]} $ I want to define
$$
\int_0^\cdot H_s dM_s, \quad t \in [0,T].
$$

I guess one could do two things:
1. Do the proof of the existence of the stochastic integral all over with processes defined on $[0,T]$
2. Reduce it to the general case. That is, define
$$
\tilde{M}_t = \begin{cases} M_t, t \in [0,T] \\
M_T, t \in [T, \infty) \end{cases}
$$
Then define $\tilde{H}$ in the same way. And then define
$$
\int_0^t H_s dM_s = \int_0^t \tilde{H}_s d \tilde{M}_s, \quad t \in [0,T].
$$

Do both approaches work?

Comment: Yeah, should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the second option: I would also like to get an existence and uniqueness  theorem like in the $[0,\infty)$ case. What is the definition of a local martingale for $[0,T]$ ?